# Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function, then $f$ attains its maximum or minimum at $x_0\in(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, reference-request, taylor-expansion

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function. Let $x_0\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(x_0)=0.$

$(i.)$ Prove that if $f''(x_0)>0$, then $x_0$ is a local minimum of $f$

$(ii.)$ Prove that if $f''(x_0)<0$, then $x_0$ is a local maximum of $f$

I think we can use the Taylor formula but I don't know how to get a proof from it.

**Taylor's Formula**

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ be a $C^{n+1}$ function. Let $x_0\in(a,b)$ and $h$, sufficiently small, then

\begin{align}f(x_0+h)=\sum^{n}_{j=0}\frac{f^{(j)}(x_0)h^{j}}{j!}+\int^{1}_{0}\frac{(1-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(x_0+th)h^{n+1} dt\end{align}

I've seen seen some proofs here that do not share the same domain or co-domain as mine. I would like to know if there are some references to this exact problem or if there are proofs, I also would appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Taylor formula is a good start. Without loss of generality assume that $f(x_0)=0$. Now notice that it reduces to $$f(x_0+h)=\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}h^2 + O(h^3), $$ and if $h$ is sufficiently small the main term dominates the remainder.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: I really crave for such a proof!

Comment: But it is almost done. For example, suppose $f''(x_0)>0$. We want to prove that $x_0$ is a local minimum, that is (since we assumed $f(x_0)=0$) $$ f(x_0+h)\ge 0,$$ for all $h$ such that $|h|$ is sufficiently small. By the Taylor formula we recalled earlier, $$f(x_0+h)=\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}h^2 + R(h),$$ where $|R(h)|\le C |h|^3$ for a constant $C\ge 0$. Because of this, if $|h|$ is sufficiently small, then $$\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}h^2 > | R(h)|, $$ and so $f(x_0+h)\ge 0$. Done.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: This can even be converted to an answer!

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: Sorry, $h$ is assumed to be very small! Does it affect the proof?

Comment: Of course not. The proof only works for small $h$ anyway. It is necessary for $h^2$ to overcome $O(h^3)$.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: I appreciate you but I need to ask this question. How did you get that \begin{align}\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}h^2>|R(h)|\end{align} and what's its essence? Also, what can we conclude from \begin{align}f(x_0+h)\geq 0?\end{align}Why also, did you assume $f(x_0)=0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing $f(x)$ with $f(x)-f(x_0)$, we can assume that $f(x_0)=0$. This is not necessary but will make some formulas shorter and clearer. To fix ideas, we suppose that $f''(x_0)>0$, as the other case is treated similarly. We claim that $x_0$ is a local minimum for $f$, which means that there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$\tag{1}\begin{array}{cc}
f(x_0+h)> 0, & \forall h\in (-\delta, \delta).
\end{array}$$

Writing the Taylor formula as you did, and using that $f'(x_0)=0$, we have 
$$\tag{2}
f(x_0+h)=\frac{f''(x_0)}{2} h^2 + R(h), \qquad\text{where } |R(h)|\le C |h|^3, $$ 
and $C> 0$ is some constant. Let $\delta= f''(x_0)/2C$. Since $|h|<\delta$, it holds that
$$
\frac{f''(x_0)}{2} h^2 > C|h|^3\ge -R(h), $$ 
and so the right-hand side of (2) is positive, which proves (1).

Comment: Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I don't think the Taylor's formula is a good way to go. Instead, note that if $f''(x_0) > 0$, then $f'(x)$ is monotone increasing in a small interval around $x_0$ (as you can show using the fact that as $f$ is $C^2$, both $f'$ and $f''$ are continuous). Now think about the limit that defines $f'(x)$: if $f'(x)$ is monotone increasing near $x_0$ what can you say about $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ for $x$ near $x_0$?

Comment: Take care than the sentence *note that if $f''(x_0) > 0$, then $f'(x)$ is monotone increasing in a small interval around $x_0$.* is not true. You can have a look [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-whose-derivative-at-0-is-one-but-which-is-not-increasing-near-0/#more-667) for a counterexample. The continuity of the derivative is required. This is the case here, but better to mention it explicitely.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  $f$ is stated to be in $C^2$ so its first and second derivatives are continuous. I'll edit the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

If $f^{\prime \prime}(x_0)>0$, we have $f^\prime(x)>0$ for $x>x_0$ close to $x_0$ and $f^\prime(x)<0$ for $x<x_0$ close to $x_0$ as we suppose $f^\prime(x_0)=0$. Consequently, $f$ is strictly positive on the right of $x_0$ and strictly negative locally on the left of $x_0$.

From that we can conclude that $x_0$ is a local minimum of $f$.

The other case is similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am grateful!